# ADB Screenshot: not found?

Tags: android, adb

My phone runs rooted 2.3.6 Gingerbread. I write these lines to take a screenshot:

```
adb shell screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png
```

It says permission denied! So I add `su`, like this:

```
adb shell "su -c 'screencap -p /sdcard/screen.png'"
```

Now when I run it, it says "screenshot: not found!"

Comment: For the first part, make sure that `/system/bin/screencap` is executable.  For the second part, try specifying a full path to `screencap`.  (You wrote "screencap" in the command but "screenshot" in the error...?)  You shouldn't need to be rooted to capture the screen -- shell should be enough.

Comment: Could you add the text of the last error you got?

Comment: I think, I have no executable screencap ..(Sorry for my wrong typing)

Comment: Surely, I have no screen cap in system/bin . How can i add this ?

Comment: Or is there any other way to take screen shot on lower versions ? Please !

Comment: Some vendors don't include screencap and other command-line utilities in their devices. I don't know of a way to install them other than to build Android yourself or install something like CyanogenMod.

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this with MonkeyRunner instead of ADB by creating a screenshot.py file with the following content:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
result = device.takeSnapshot()
result.writeToFile('<some path>/screenshot.png','png')
```

and run it with the command (on Windows)

`<android sdk path>\tools\monkeyrunner.bat <some path>\screenshot.py`

Comment: Awesome, worked, thanks! NOTES: the `<some path>/screenshot.png` is a path on the non-mobile system (i.e. same where screenshot.py is, your PC); and for `<some path>\screenshot.py` you must provide full path, so if it's in the current dir, you can use: `%CD%\screenshot.py`